# Google App Script Error Message - Exception: Too many simultaneous invocations: Spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I keep getting the following 'Exception: Too many simultaneous invocations: Spreadsheets' error message.

It seems that every time a new entry is added to the spreadsheet, its triggers the script to run from the 1st entry instead of the mostly recently added.

Not only is it causing the quota to get maxed out, but it is also duplicating records.

Please advise on how to edit the code below to pull from the most recent entry.

```
function pullDataFromSheet() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheetname = "example_events";
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
    var sheetLR = sheet.getLastRow(); 
    var sheetLC = sheet.getLastColumn(); 
    var dataSR = 2; 
    
    var sourceRange = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheetLR-dataSR+1,sheetLC);

    
    var sourceData = sourceRange.getValues();
    
    var sourceLen = sourceData.length;


    for (var i=0;i<sourceLen;i++){
    if(sourceData[i][1] !== '') {
        var data = {};
        var emailLabel = sourceData[i][1];
        console.log(emailLabel);
        var userEmail = emailLabel;
        postEventData(emailLabel)

        var userName = sourceData [i][2];
        console.log(userName);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function pullDataFromSheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive("example_events");
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("");
  var sr = 2;
  var rg = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1, sh.getLastColumn());
  var vs = rg.getValues();
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (r[1]) {
      console.log('email: %s user: %s', r[1], r[2])
    }
  });
}
```